# Overloading the == operator in custom implementation of a stack

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to implement a custom stack that always returns the min element. Effectively thus I'm maintaining two stacks. I've implemented the push method in my custom stack but feel at a bit of a loss implementing the pop. Ideally I'm trying to write a custom overload of for the == operator two compare two nodes.
This is my node implementation.

```
template<typename T> class stack;
template<typename T> class node{
friend class stack<T>;
public:
    node():T(NULL),next(NULL){}
    node(T data):data(data), next(NULL){}
private:
    T data;
    node<T>* next;

};
```

And here's my stack push and pop

```
void push(T item){
        node<T>* N = new node<T>(item);

        if(top == nullptr){
            top = N;
            min_top = N;
            ++elements;
            return;
        }
        if(item < min_top->data) N->next = min_top;
        min_top = N;
        N->next = top;
        top = N;
        ++elements;
    }
```

...........
...........

```
T pop(){
        if(top == nullptr)throw std::runtime_error("stack empty");

        T item = top->data;
        node<T>* P = top;
        top = P->next;
        delete P;
        --elements;
        return item;

    }
```

This is the method signature I've defined for the equality overload.

```
bool operator==(const node<T>& other){

    }
```

The idea is to pop the minimum element(top of the min stack) of the min_stack if it's the same as the top of the main stack.

Comment: First, relational operators ought to be `const` on both operands, not just the right hand one.  Then, you need `operator<` for what you're doing, not `operator==`.

Comment: @BenVoigt ,so effectively you're suggesting I compare this to that. Equality is exactly what I'm trying to overload.

Comment: Finally, the `if (item < min_top->data)` in your `push` isn't doing anything for you, since `N->next` always gets overwritten immediately.

Comment: @Clockwork I think that this construction node():T(NULL),next(NULL){} is invalid is not it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that wasn't really the doubt, but in any case, I'm curious, why would it be invalid?

Comment: @Clockwork: Because `T` isn't a pointer (is it)?  Only pointers can be null.

Comment: @Clockwork T is not a data member of the class nor its base subobject.

Comment: Well I'm not a C++ pro, but from what I understand in C++11 move semantics, T gets determined at compile time if it is used. This code works fine. However I'd be open to knowing what will be the correct approach.

Comment: @Clockwork: Is this your real code, cut and paste from source file into the question, or did you retype it?

Comment: @Clockwork According to the C++ Standard "Unless the mem-initializer-id names the constructor’s class, a non-static data member of the constructor’s class, or a direct or virtual base of that class, the mem-initializer is ill-formed." I think you mean data() instead of T( NULL )

Comment: @Clockwork I do not think that you need the operator. You could simply compare data members data of the main stack and the auxiliary stack.

Comment: @Clockwork Maybe this link will be useful for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409655/get-the-minimum-element-of-a-stack-in-o1-time/31411859#31411859

Comment: I think I figured out the T thing. Should this be the correct constructor signature.  node( ):T(0),next(nullptr){ }

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `operator<` (which you need for a sorted collection of any type), then there's a pattern for correctly defining `operator==`:

```
bool operator==(const node<T>& other) const
{
    if (*this < other) return false;
    if (other < *this) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Or you can make it even more general using `std::less`:

```
bool operator==(const node<T>& other) const
{
    using std::less;
    if (less(*this, other)) return false;
    if (less(other, *this)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here, isn't the idea to compare both the data and the next item in the node comparison. By dereferencing this are we not just comparing the data.

Comment: @Clockwork: This is the usual meaning for `operator==`, and it uses whatever members of `this` are checked inside `operator<`.  If you have some other meaning of node equality, that requires looking at more than one node, I suggest you give it a more descriptive name and don't call it `operator==`.  Things in the standard library may break if you have two items `a` and `b` and `a<b`, `b<a`, `a==b` are all false.